# Read INI file from Windows\System32 folder

Tags: delphi, ini

Why we can't read a .ini file from Windows\System32 folder?

using this example:

```
ReadIniFile := TIniFile.Create(Format('%s\System32\%s', [GetEnvironmentVariable('WINDIR'), 'File.ini']));
Result  := ReadIniFile.ReadString('HWID', 'A', '');
ReadIniFile .Free;
```

return a null string, now if remove "System32" and try read from Windows folder read fine.

Comment: One has to wonder why you have ini files in that directory

Answer (score 4):

If you compile your app as 32-bit, but run it on a 64-bit version of Windows, then your code is actually trying to read the INI file from the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\` folder instead of the `C:\Windows\System32\` folder.  See [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/file-system-redirector) for more details.  You can use the `sysnative` alias to access the real `System32` folder when running under WOW64:

```
function GetWindowsFolder: string
var
  Folder: array[0..MAX_PATH-1] of Char;
  Len: UINT;
begin
  Len := GetWindowsDirectory(Folder, MAX_PATH);
  if (Len > 0) and (Len < MAX_PATH) then
    Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Folder)
  else;
    Result := '';
end;

function GetSystemFolder: string;
var
  Folder: array[0..MAX_PATH-1] of Char;
  Len: UINT;
begin
  Len := GetSystemDirectory(Folder, MAX_PATH);
  if (Len > 0) and (Len < MAX_PATH) then
    Result := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Folder)
  else
    Result := '';
end;

function GetRealSystem32Folder: string
var
  IsWow64: BOOL;
begin
  if IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), @IsWow64) and IsWow64 then
  begin
    Result := GetWindowsFolder;
    if Result <> '' then
      Result := Result + 'sysnative' + PathDelim;
  end else
    Result := GetSystemFolder;
end;

...

var
  ReadIniFile: TIniFile;
begin
  ReadIniFile := TIniFile.Create(GetRealSystem32Folder + 'File.ini');
  ...
end;
```

Note that the `sysnative` alias works under WOW64 only, so if you don't want to dynamically format a file path based on whether WOW64 is used or not, then you can simply disable the Redirector temporarily instead:

```
var
  ReadIniFile: TIniFile;
  SysFolder: array[0..MAX_PATH-1] of Char;
  Len: UINT;
  Value: Pointer;
begin
  Result := '';
  if not Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(@Value) then Exit;
  try
    Len := GetSystemDirectory(SysFolder, MAX_PATH);
    if (Len > 0) and (Len < MAX_PATH) then
    begin
      ReadIniFile := TIniFile.Create(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(SysFolder) + 'File.ini');
      ...
    end;
  finally
    Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(Value);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, bit disabling redirection is extremely dubious and almost certainly should not be done.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan perhaps, though in this situation, disabling the redirector is safe, as the disabled block is small and isolated, and the 2 Wow64 API functions being used affect only the calling thread, not globally. Granted, using `sysnative` is preferred, but disabling the redirector is still an option, so I mention both.

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling your program as 32-bit, it is trying to read the ini file from the SysWOW64 directory. If you compile the program for 64-bit it should be fine. You can disable redirection by Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection, more informations:
[Could not find system file when it actually exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603087/could-not-find-system-file-when-it-actually-exists)

Comment: This reads like a recommendation to disable redirection. Which is a bad idea.

Comment: I'm asking that, because i need write a file and hide it from others peoples, since more applications will read/write on that. (it's not a virus). Some advice for that?