# Cannot see/execute "c:\windows\system32\rdpclip.exe" from Delphi code, but can see it and execute it using the same user login in File Explorer

Tags: delphi, shellexecute, findfirst

I am trying to execute `c:\windows\system32\rdpclip.exe` from my Delphi program (Delphi CE 10.4) on Windows 10.

I can see and execute this file just fine from Windows Explorer or from a CMD window, but when I try to use `FileExists('c:\windows\system32\rdpclip.exe')` it comes back with error 2 (file not found). If I use `ShellExecute()` to start it, I get file not found as well.

I can see and execute `c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe` from my Delphi code just fine. No special attributes are set on `rdpclip.exe` - they are the same as those on `cmd.exe`. The user ID is a member of local administrators, and UAC control is set to "Disable" running all admins in admin approval mode.

I also found that if I list the contents of the `c:\windows\system32` folder using `FindFirst()`/`FindNext()`, a lot of files (including `rdpclip.exe`) are not listed, while others are (for example, `rdpsa.exe` shows up in the list, while `rdpclip.exe` does not).

`rdpclip.exe` shows up in File Explorer, and can be started manually from the "Run" prompt in Windows. It is NOT visible in my Delphi program using `ShellExecute()` or `FindFirst()`/`FindNext()`.

Other files in the same folder (`cmd.exe`, `rdpsa.exe`) are visible, and can be executed from the same Delphi program, using the same line of code (just changing the file name).

The expectation was, of course, that my Delphi program would behave the same way as File Explorer in Windows behaves.

File attributes are no different on all of those files, and effective access control shows that the current user has read/execute to all of the files in question.

Comment: Is it a 32-bit application? I bet it is, and that you will find the file if you compile your app as 64-bit instead.

Comment: If your app is 32bit, use ```c:\windows\sysnative\``` instead of ```c:\windows\system32\``` to access the 64bit `system32` folder. Or use [`Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-wow64disablewow64fsredirection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your program is not finding `rdpclip.exe` file is beacuse on 64 bit version of windows folder `Windows\System32` doesn't actually hold any 32 bit libraries or programs as one might expect but instead it contains all 64 bit libraries and programs.

32 bit libraries and programs can actually be located in `Windows\SysWOW64` folder instead. So when any 32 bit application is trying to access `System32` folder it is automatically redirected into `Sys64WOW` folder. And if you check the `Sys64WOW` folder you will see that there is no `rdpclip.exe` file located there.

I recommend you read more about [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) to better understand your problem.

---

EDIT: You can avoid `System32` folder redirection by using `Sysnative` as it is explained in [Could not find system file when it actually exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15603174/3636228)

Comment: Thank you, this looks like the real reason I am having this problem. What would be the "correct" way of dealing with this?  Disable redirector before calling ShellExecute and re-enable it right after?  Are there other ways to deal with it (I am concerned that should something happen while the redirector is disabled, it can cause other issues for the system before I get a chance to reenable it)

Comment: What problem are you trying to deal with?

Comment: @Vlad I edited my answer with a link to an answer on how to avoid File System redirection when accessing `System32` folder. This is one of the answer that are here on SO about this topic. I know they are more but didn't manage to find them now.

Comment: Thank you @SilverWarior - "sysnative" did the trick, and was easy to implement!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

You're hard-coding the path to **System32**. Starting with Windows 95 (when **System** folder was introduced) that is wrong; that code is buggy.

You **must** use:

- [`SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_System)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) - Windows Vista or later
- [`SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_SYSTEM)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha) - Windows 2000 or later
- [`SHGetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDL_SYSTEM)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetspecialfolderpatha) - Windows 95 or later

Hard-coding the path to the **System** folder is always wrong.

Comment: Although what you suggest is accurate (don't forget `GetSystemDirectory()`, too), it is not the root cause of the problem, or the fix for this particular issue. The OP will still run into the same problem regardless of how the path to the `system32` folder is obtained. The [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) is the real culprit here. The OP's app is trying to find/run the 32bit version of `rdpclip.exe`, which doesn't exist, only a 64bit version exists

Comment: Thank you - I always obtain the system folder names via system calls rather than hard coding them; I simply used it here as an illustration for clarity.
Looks like the System Redirector is the real issue, I need to look into it further